# Upgrade console ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS to 15.10

Tags: 15.10, do-release-upgrade, 16.04

How to upgrade 14.04.3 LTS to 15.10 (wily)?

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

offers upgrade to 16.04 (xenial), which is in beta current.

(It is a server, no GUI.)

Comment: To upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10 you'll have to upgrade thru 14.10 and 15.04 first.

Comment: @xangua Ok, how to upgrade to 14.10? `do-release-upgrade` tells me that "No new release found". `do-release-upgrade -d` offers upgrade to 16.04 beta

Comment: What I would question here is: why do you need to upgrade to 15.10?

Comment: @xangua because 16.04 is not released yet. But I don't want to talk about 15.10 vs 16.04, so question is: Is it possible to upgrade to 15.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the following file

`sudo vi /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`

and change from 
`Prompt=lts` to `Prompt=normal`

This will allow you to upgrade to the next release which is 14.10 and then you can rerun the command to upgrade to the next.

Comment: Oh yeah, it works!