# Upgrade from 14.04 (LTS) to 15.10

Tags: 14.04, 15.10

I'm using my old computer to run ubuntu at the moment. It has a radeon h6xxxm graphics card and it's not supported by v16.04. (So bad battery life in the newest version. I need catalyst control center to switch to intel graphics) 
How can I upgrade to the version of Ubuntu before they stoped supporting my graphics card, which would be 15.10?

So in summary how would I upgrade to the second newest version of ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Open `Updates`(probably named `Update manager`), click on `Updates` tab and select `Notify me about new version: Any new version` (or so, I have different language installed).
Then, run your update manager and it should give you an option to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 1 question: this is the next version or the 'newest' version?

Comment: As far as I remember, it should first show you your very next version, (14.10), then 15.04 and finally 15.10. If not, follow this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/717518/upgrade-console-ubuntu-14-04-3-lts-to-15-10